# Existence of data when mean vector and covariance matrix (p.s.d.) is fixed?

Tags: covariance-matrix, mean, deterministic

I would like to prove that for any positive semidefinite matrix $\Sigma_{n\times n}$ and any vector $\mu_{n\times1}$, are there always data points (no matter how many, as long as finite) whose empirical covariance matrix is $\Sigma_{n\times n}$ and the empirical vector is $\mu_{n\times1}$. What is the way to prove it rigorously?

Comment: Feels like it could be shown by giving a way to construct such a sample - easy along one dimension, perhaps not much more difficult with more dimensions?

Comment: @josliber and Björn thanks for your comments! I figured out that by Cholesky decomposition, one can easily show $\Simga$ and $\mu$ can be reconstructed by $n+1$ data points. And I will mark this question as duplicated.